# Set AWS Authorizer entry for ASP.NET Core lambda function serverless.template file

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to set an already existing authorizer function on my .Net Core Web API app. 
When I use purely aws lambda nodejs, the .yml file to accomplish it, looks like this:

```
custom:
  defaultStage: test
  currentStage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage} 
  defaultRegion: us-east-1
  currentRegion: ${opt:region, self:custom.defaultRegion}
  **defaultAuthorizer**: us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:function:TypeToken-test-Authorizer
  **currentAuthorizer**: ${opt:authorizer, self:custom.defaultAuthorizer}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: ${self:custom.currentStage}
  profile: ${opt:profile, "default"} 
  region: ${self:custom.currentRegion}

functions:
  MyFunctionName:
    handler: handlerTestAPI.myFunctionName
    events:
      - http:
          path: myFunctionName
          method: post
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
          **authorizer:**
            arn: arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.currentAuthorizer}
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            type: token
```

For this case, the ASP.NET Core App *serverless.template* file is similar to this:

```
"Resources" : {

    "AspNetCoreFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "Test.API::Project.API.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
            "TestTable" : { "Fn::If" : ["CreateProjectTable", {"Ref":"ProjectTable"}, { "Ref" : "ProjectTableName" } ] }
          }
        },
        "Events": {
          "PutResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have searched for templates where an existing authorizer is set on top of a .net core serverless function using serverless.template file, but haven't found one yet.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a widely requested feature but not supported yet [until a few day](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/pull/546)s ago

The github page is now updated

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api

Now you can use the AUTH property

```
Auth configuration for this specific Api+Path+Method. Useful for overriding the API's DefaultAuthorizer or setting auth config on an individual path when no DefaultAuthorizer is specified.
```

The default template generate an implicit API gateway. To set anthorizer, you may need to [create an explicit API gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyRlX.jpg)

Also, there is an [example](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/release/v1.8.0/examples/2016-10-31/api_lambda_request_auth/template.yaml) on their Github page

Comment: I saw this option too some days ago and tried something like: 

"Events": {
 "PutResource": {
 "Type": "Api",
 "Properties": {
 "Path": "/{proxy+}",
 "Method": "ANY",
 "Auth": {
  "DefaultAuthorizer": "MyAuthorizer",
  "Authorizers": {
   "MyAuthorizer": {
    "FunctionPayloadType": "TOKEN",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:1234343545:function:MyAuthorizer-env-Lambda"
   }
  }
 } 
     }
}

But I don't see any changes being applied on the API Gateway console regarding the authorizer configuration after deploying it with the updated serverless file.

Comment: @CoderRoller can you go to your console => CloudFormation => your API => [Edit template in designer] and see if there is any change reflected on the generated JSON?

Comment: I  see it in the original template: Events":{"PutResource":{"Type":"Api","Properties":{"Path":"/{proxy+}","Method":"ANY","Auth":{"DefaultAuthorizer":"MyAuthorizer"}}, but I don't see it in the processed template.I have latest version installed .NetCore SDK and AWS tools for Visual Studio 2017 btw.

Comment: @CoderRoller I just checked the latest version. The default template generate an implicit API gateway. To set anthorizer, I needed to create an explicit API gateway. This should be easier for you to understand
https://imgur.com/OkM9vpo And the GitHub example page
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/release/v1.8.0/examples/2016-10-31/api_lambda_request_auth/template.yaml

Comment: I tried the config here: https://imgur.com/EYwgRcs, but is giving me rollback completed, when i see the event logs i see this: https://imgur.com/a/1qZvkWo, note that i am just using an already deployed authorizer and its ARN, so I don't have the MyAuthFunction part you have in your image. Do I need that too?, or could only be a permissions issue now?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like just a permission issue for me. That part I'm not sure. Maybe you can create a separate question for that. I will update the last comment to the answer